# MERN simple app CORS error issue - POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting,

`Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/content' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

and

for my FE(react)
and getting syntax err for BE(node),

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
```

I have no issue with GET request but I can't POST.
Here is my FE

```
  addContent = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.title),
        // mode:'cors', --> tried after researching but it didn't solve my issue
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText)
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('addContent failed -', err)
    }
  }
```

Here is my BE

```
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://localhost:3000'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus:200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Also, when I POST with postman, I was able to POST(got 200) however, it only returns _id. there is no body(content title that I want to post)

I read many articles that explained about cors issue but I couldn't find right answer to solve my issue. Please assume me as beginner of programing.. Thank you ahead!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
addContent = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.title),
        // mode:'cors', --> tried after researching but it didn't solve my issue
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'

        }
      });

      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText)
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('addContent failed -', err)
    }
  }
```

And also you can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

And I suggest try once without using cors at express.

```
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://localhost:3000'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus:200
}

//app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Shivprasad. I tried both and both of them returns me these errors. `localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/content' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: I wonder why I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0` in BE.

Comment: what data format are you returning from server?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me again. I just figured this out. The issue was this.state.content.title not only title - because this is how I designed my code in server side. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

Your error here, means that you are not allowed to access localhost:9000 from any other URL.
I recommend you take a look at this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

If you want your API to be accessed by anyone, you can set your "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to "*".
Here is a full explanation of this header purpose (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: so where should I exactly add that in my code? I am sorry I am very beginner of programming. I read all your reference links and I don't find solution. Can you tell me exactly which line of my code I should add?